Movie set in the 70's with a murderer talking with a dog
I'm looking for a film and feature film. The scene that I saw was a serial murderer who speak to neighbor's dogs in new york.
In another scene, we see some people confuse the murderer with a punk. In another scene the weather becomes hot in NY and people break in a cold room. I think the film is between 1990-2000, by the aesthetics of the image is dry day time and is reaching 70.

Could it be Summer of Sam, a movie by Spike Lee about the Son of Sam murders?  Here are the similarities to what you described:

Talking to dogs 


Punk character - From Wikipedia: "Vinny is approached by Ritchie, an old friend. Ritchie has become part of the punk rock scene and his unusual dress and hairstyle concerns Vinny and others in the neighborhood."
Was made in 1999, but is set in the 70s.

